# How can transfer biblio nodes from old site to new site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a lot of biblio nodes in old site. Now I want to transfer them to new site. I need a way to make a **bulk biblio export**. 
I think *node export* module is not a good choice because it ruin nids, vids and node consistency. Is there any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially for biblio I used its *biblio* page export. I filtered my desired biblios and exported them to endnote type. Then I imported them to my new site.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to use the module [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) to import your nodes from your old site.

Comment: Thanks. Although I found a bulk export in biblio page, but your answer is a general answer for transferring data.